# Anyone know how to alter an FFMPEG command to output at half the size?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an FMPEG command to scale down a video and add a blur to the background to fill the remaining height to 1136, plus add an overlay image, but it comes out at double the size I want. I am trying to get the whole video down to a 640 width without the overlay video being cropped or sized up. I've tried switching around every number but can't seem to get it to work with a width of 640. Thank you for any help.

```
ffmpeg -i '/z.mp4' -i '/a.png' -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=128/81*iw:128/41*ih,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/40:luma_power=3:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/40:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]scale=1280:720,overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1,crop=w=iw*81/128[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=82.8:118.8" '/h.mp4';
```

Comment: Unclear. What's the original video resolution? What's the intended res for the blurred BG? for the video overlay?

Comment: 1280x738. I added the test video I am using on WeTransfer if you want to try it with that [link]https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3c0da7f3e5d15df62fbbb5be1d3fe6420180618184949/555c52382dacbdb2037011598ad54b6f20180618184949/e26e1e It's just a clip from the Wonder Woman trailer. The intended res is 640 width and  1136 height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i '/z.mp4' -i '/a.png'
       -filter_complex
          "[0:v]scale=-1:1136,
                boxblur=lr=min(h\,w)/40:lp=3:cr=min(cw\,ch)/40:cp=1,crop=640:1136[bg];
           [0:v]scale=640:-1[vid];
           [bg][vid]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[bg];
           [bg][1:v]overlay=82.8:118.8,setsar=1" '/h.mp4'
```

Comment: It works for the overlay video but the background video width is compressed and the height is stretched do you know a way to fix that? I added two pictures of what i am trying to get and what the output is. [link]https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a2eb0441f2c52738c2b9a2c74a7ad02b20180618194946/469b26

Comment: Thank you for the help Gyan. Also you might want to edit out the typo, overlay=overlay= is written twice.